# JQuery Mobile: customize panel widget size

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I'm using the panel widget of JQuery Mobile: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/panel/

It looks very nice on phones, but on tablet devices the panel is too small with respect to the screen size. 
How can I scale the panel size and its content to the 50% of the screen?

I tried using transform:scale(1.5), but it has a lot of side effects, then I tried to customize the css according to the last part of the page http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/panel/, but nothing changed.

Is there a simple way to modify the framework or to dynamically change the size of the elements without creating side effects?

Comment: Could you find the way to do this?